# exclude-result-prefixes not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to write an xslt transform that does not include any @xmlns:* attributes in the root element of the output. Given this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jw:root xmlns:jw="http://lexisnexis.com/neptune/gtdttest/jw">
    <jw:a/>
    <b test="1">
        <c/>
    </b>
</jw:root>
```

and this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:jw="http://namespace/test/jw" exclude-result-prefixes="jw">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>

         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@test"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jw:root xmlns:jw="http://lexisnexis.com/neptune/gtdttest/jw">
    <jw:a/>
    <b>
        <c/>
    </b>
</jw:root>
```

I tried
- putting the @exclude-result-prefixes on the root template, 
- not copying the attributes, 
- not using 'copy' in identity template but using 
- using #all

I read in the spec, although I can't find it now, that `<xsl:copy/>` ignores @exclude-result-prefixes, and that other thing can override it as well.

any way to remove those @xmlns:[prefix] atts? The ns's are defined in the dtd that the output uses, and it screws me up to have them there. Guess I will have to make a separate pass just opening with java and remove that way?

thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note: the namespaces in the XML and the XSLT are not the same.

Comment: `exclude-result-prefixes` only works for literal result elements you create in your XSLT code, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#lre-namespaces. If you have namespaces in your input you need to transform the elements or in generally the nodes in a namespace and to create new elements or in generally nodes within no namespace. Furthermore you haven't really explained which result you want, as "an xslt transform that does not include any @xmlns:* attributes in the root element" sounds as if you want `<jw:root>...</jw:root>`, a result which would not even be namespace well-formed XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exclude-result-prefixes attribute (a) only works for literal result elements, and (b) only eliminates namespaces that are *unused* - a namespace that is used in the name of an element or attribute will always be declared in the result tree.

What you are trying to achieve is to modify the input elements to be in a different namespace. That can't be done with xsl:copy, which always keeps the name of the elements (namespace + local name) intact. You need to create a new element using `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`.

If you give your result elements and attributes the right name, the namespace declarations will take care of themselves. Remember that the name of an element or attribute is a (namespace, localname) pair.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the *identity template* use the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If your source XML has also **attributes** with namespaces,
then add also the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, this approach works as long as you have no "ovelapping" element /
attribute names (same name with diffrent namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

`copy-namespaces="no"`  works for me using `xsl:copy-of`